# Update multiple documents instance in MongoDb collection with Mongoose. save() is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, apollo-server

Mongoose newbe here. I got the following function to update the references (deleting them) in the document Post when a Tag is deleted. When I call my GraphQl API this is what I got:

```
message": "posts.save is not a function"
```

The function in my gql resolver:

```
          async deleteTag(root, { id }, context) {
                const posts = await Post.find();
                const tag = await Tag.findById(id);
                if(!tag){
                    const error = new Error('Tag not found!');
                    error.code = 404;
                    throw error;
                }
                posts?.forEach(async (post) => {
                    await post.tags.pull(id);
                })
                await posts.save()
                await Tag.findByIdAndRemove(id);
                return true;
            }
```

This is the Post model:

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    tags: {
        type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: 'Tag',
        required: false
    },
});
```

and this is the Tag model:

```
const TagSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
```

Looks like I can't call the method **save()** on the array of objects returned by **Exercise.find()**

I used the same pattern in other functions, the difference is that there I used **.findById()**

Any solution? Advice and best practice advide are super welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the posts individually:

```
posts?.forEach(async (post) => {
  await post.tags.pull(id);
  await post.save();
})
```

Or use [`Model.updateMany()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.updateMany) combined with the [`$pull` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/).

FWIW, you should probably limit the number of matching `Post` documents by selecting only documents that have the specific tag listed:

```
await Post.find({ 'tags._id' : id });
```